# All my Toasts' text are being displayed off center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-toast

How do I fix this? I have not done anything to theme `TextAppearance` - I am simply using `AppCompatActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`. Could this be a bug in the support library?
[image: off center toast]

Comment: Please post code here ..

Comment: please post code here so that we can inspect.

Comment: Try to set Toast Gravity like : toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Comment: I think it has to do with `android:fitsSystemWindows`, verifying now

Comment: @HareshChhelana it happens to toasts created by the framework, like the long press action bar menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `android:fitsSystemWindows` == true in my theme caused this